# GLFW - hold window without using loop

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glfw

In order to hold the result open (the window screen) I have to do the following:

```
while (glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED))
{
    // do some stuff
    glDrawPixels(...);
    glfwSwapBuffers();
}
```

But this loops through the body of the while loop until I stop it. I don't want to render in real time.

Does GLFW have an equivalent to the SDL_WaitEvent:

```
SDL_Surface* screen;
// do something with screen
SDL_Flip(screen);

SDL_Event event;
while (SDL_WaitEvent(&event))
{
   // handle input
}
```

If I try to do something like this, the program renders the result but after a while it stops responding:

```
//do stuff
glDrawPixels(...);
glfwSwapBuffers();

while (glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED))
{
   if (glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC) == GLFW_PRESS)
   {
       glfwTerminate();
   }
}
```

Comment: `SDL_WaitEvent` has it's own internal loop. The point of GLFW is that it gives *you* control. If you are concerned about CPU usage, just sleep for a few milliseconds inside the loop.

Comment: I want to measure the render time. But when I measure it in the loop, it have to calculate it on each iteration - It might be not CPU consuming but if I can find a workaround would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLFW3 has a `glfwWaitEvents` that will probably do what you want.

http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga554e37d781f0a997656c26b2c56c835e

Comment: neither `SDL_WaitEvent` nor `glfwWaitEvents` are good candidates for rendering loops in applications, unless you specifically want to draw a frame and then wait for input of some kind.  The most common use case is to draw a scene, then process input if any exists, and then draw the scene again regardless of whether the user pressed a key or clicked a mouse.

Comment: Yep, that actually did what I was trying to achieve, thanks !

Comment: @Jherico, GLFW have [`glfwPostEmptyEvent`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#gab5997a25187e9fd5c6f2ecbbc8dfd7e9) to start the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your typical GLFW main application loop should probably look something like this:

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
  glfwPollEvents();
  update();
  draw();
  glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
glfwDestroyWindow(window);
```

Input can be handled via a callback such as the keyboard input callback.  I use a wrapper class to handle my GLFW stuff so after I create a window I do something like this:

```
glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, this);
glfwSetKeyCallback(window, glfwKeyCallback);
```

And my keyboard callback looks like this:

```
void glfwKeyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
  GlfwApp * instance = (GlfwApp *) glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);
  instance->onKey(key, scancode, action, mods);
}
```

and the base class implementation of the onKey method looks like this:

```
void GlfwApp::onKey(int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
  if (GLFW_PRESS != action) {
    return;
  }
  switch (key) {
  case GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE:
    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, 1);
    return;
  }
}
```

You can see the whole class [here](https://github.com/jherico/OculusRiftInAction/blob/master/source/common/GlfwApp.cpp) and [here](https://github.com/jherico/OculusRiftInAction/blob/master/source/common/GlfwApp.h) .

Comment: Hello. Can I use [`glfwWaitEvents`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga554e37d781f0a997656c26b2c56c835e) instead of `glfwPollEvents();`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using glfwGetWindowParam() I think you may want to look into using glfwWindowShouldClose(). It takes in a pointer to the GLFW window. Here's a link to the GLFW docs page that has glfwWindowShouldClose() http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html

Comment: Does that come with the standard GLFW package, because it says "undefined" to me. In the example they are including glfw3.h , but I have only glfw.h

Comment: It's a GLFW3 function. You must have an older version of GLFW.